# R Scripts Open Blank

Tags: r, rstudio

When I save my R scripts and try to reopen them the script is suddenly blank. Nor an update of R and RStudio or reopening it with a different encoding helped me to solve this issue. Does any one know why this error occurs. I didn't even closed RStudio inbetween when this started to happen for the first time.

I've been working already quite a while with R but nether experienced something like this.
Thank you all!

Comment: Do you see the files in your OS? If you make a long script, does your OS see the file size as having non-0 length? What if you open the files in another editor (e.g., notepad)?

Comment: Have you tried "reopen with enconding" from the file menu?

Comment: Hi Gregor, I tried to reopen the file with encoding already. Unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem. I created already a file on my other computer than send it to my windows where I have the issue. As soon as I opened the script there the file size would switch to non-0. After that the code is not visible regardless with which file the script is opened.